# Application crashed when I tried to get value from other activity, why?

Tags: java, android, class, arraylist, get

So in one Activity I set an ArrayList in a class and in the other Activity I want to get the ArrayList, but when I try to get those information the application is crashing.

ERROR:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.sander.onzeoptocht, PID: 3749
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sander.onzeoptocht/com.example.sander....t.deelnemer}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.example.sander....mDataObject.deelnemerInfo

Set Activity:

```
ArrayList<alleDeelnemers> deelnemers = new ArrayList<>();

//deelnemer is a class with ID and some strings.
deelnemers.add(deelnemer);

//set arraylist in class
deelnemerInfo info = new deelnemerInfo();
info.setDeelnemerGegevens(deelnemers);
```

Class:

```
public class deelnemerInfo extends Application {

ArrayList<alleDeelnemers> deelnemerGegevens;

public ArrayList<alleDeelnemers> getDeelnemerGegevens() {
    return deelnemerGegevens;
}
public void setDeelnemerGegevens(ArrayList<alleDeelnemers> deelnemerGegevens) {
    this.deelnemerGegevens = deelnemerGegevens;
}
```

Get Activity:

```
deelnemerInfo info = ((deelnemerInfo)getApplicationContext());

Log.e("test", String.valueOf(info.getDeelnemerGegevens().get(0).getAantalvolgnummer()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that `getApplicationContext()` return the context of the entire application, not just your activity? Try using `GetContext()`. Furthermore, the type of your ArrayList is alleDeelnemers, which looks kind of strange to me.

groetjes,

Comment: Ey Rob, zal ik de class van 'alleDeelnemers' erbij zetten? Dan snap je het misschien beter. Ik zal nu is 'GetContext()' proberen.

Comment: Maar 'GetContext()' wordt rood bij mij. Ik weet ook niet precies hoe ik dat moet gebruiken.

Comment: I suggest as a friendly advice, to try to code in English :) and to speak English on SO :) Met vriendelijke groeten

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't (at least I don't know of any way) just get a variable from another activity, when you define it in your set activity your scope is just that activity. When you want to pass a value into another activity you can either link them through a different thread, e.g. an `AsyncTask` or you pass them as Extras.

Secondly I don't quite understand how you want to get your delmeneerInfo by setting it `getApplicationContext()`. That does not return any variable you set in a previous activity, but rather just what it says, the application context. Which, your error message says it, cannot be cast to your class:  `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.example.sander....mDataObject.deelnemerInfo`

You can also try working with your own extension of the Application Class to create somehting like global variables, have a look here: https://www.mobomo.com/2011/05/how-to-use-application-object-of-android/

Comment: I already knew that, sorry. I was just trying to do a lot of things, and I already knew of AsyncTask but I can't use that method.

Comment: I don't know how to add my Array in an Extras

Comment: Don't know what's in your Array, you might be able to condense it into a Serializable Extra or a whole lot of String Extras. You can also look into extending your Application Class, I updated my answer.

Comment: Wait I said I can't use AsyncTask, but I think I can. Maybe I know a solution, so tomorrow I will try to use AsyncTask.

Comment: I got a class with a lot of set and get (int and string). In a for loop I add values into the class and that class is added in the array.